# ddd no debug symbols are found

Tags: c, debugging, cygwin, ddd-debugger

I build my project with "./configure CFLAGS=-g3" , also tried "make CFLAGS=-g3".
when I load slim.exe with ddd, it say no debug symbols are found.

How can I create slim.exe with debug symbols, and I load it to ddd and perform debugging?

is there any chance that debug is disabled in configure.ac ?

I am not familiar with automaketools and Linux, now using cygwin on windows. 
I searched solutions, but failed.

could anyone point out my mistakes?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your compiler is gcc, the [option to enable debug output is `-g`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options), there's no number after it. It looks like you're confusing it with the optimization flag family `-O1` and so on.

Also, to set the environment variable, you need to do it before running the command, in general:

```
$ CFLAGS=-g make
```

And with autoconfig, it's ususally an option:

```
$ ./configure --enable-debug
```

You can run `./configure --help` to view the available options, and since `configure` will lead to Makefile(s) being created, you must always do it *before* trying to build the project by running `make`.

The sequence is, typically:

1. `cd project`
2. `./configure --help` to review the options, look for `--enable-debug`
3. `./configure --enable-debug` to run the autoconfig script, creating Makefile(s)
4. `make`

Comment: "./configure CFLAGS=-g" , after "make". I tried those, and still same message

Comment: could you please tell me in steps, I am little confused

Comment: It still saying that no debug symbols found. is that the problem of DDD? I don't think so, what to do now?